# Putting 'Contents' link on pdf?

Tags: pdf

I have several pdf's consisting of handwritten notes which I typically use 'Okular' to view. Since they are handwritten they have no formatting and therefore  no 'Contents' menu (as seen on Okular). Is there a way which I can add such links to my pdf's so that I can navigate them more easily?

Answer (score 1):

Am I too late here ? pdftk has a updateinfo option which merges metadata into document. I use this option to generate TOC links to gnuplot pdf output. you need to generate a text document such as:

**Bookmarks.txt**

```
  BookmarkBegin
  BookmarkTitle: Bookmark Title
  BookmarkLevel: 1
  BookmarkPageNumber: PageNumber
```

and then:

pdftk  Mypdf.pdf update_info Bookmarks.txt output bookmark_Mypdf.pdf

You will have to find the way of automating the procedure. For sure there is a way of doing this on gui, but i dont know any.

hope this helps.